# Get Xml field from database, then get value from a particular element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to store a particular element's values from xml documents that I retrieve from the database (if and only if the xml document has it) into a list of ints.

I have started my attempt to do so like this (messages.MessageXML is an Xml type in an SQL Server database):

```
    List<int> messageXml = (from messages in dbContext.Messages
                               join transactions in dbContext.Transactions
                               on messages.TransactionID equals transactions.TransactionID 
                               where transactions.CreatedOn >= StartDate
                               && transactions.CreatedOn <= EndDate
                               select messages.MessageXML
                               ).ToList();
```

Is what I am wanting to do possible in one LINQ query, or do I need to place messages.MessageXML into a List of XmlDocuments / Strings and then try to query for it that way? I can do that, but I would prefer just to have it all done in one query.

I tried to do this based off of some other questions that I have seen:

```
select messages.MessageXML.Element("IDThatIWant")
```

But I keep getting an error that states that 'string' does not contain a definition for Element. If it is a namespace that I'm missing, I'm not sure which one it is.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would do it (if possible, I don't know if LINQ to XML will/may handle this for you) server side on SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create and dereference the XML-Linq on the fly in the select clause, like this:

```
select XElement.Parse(messages.MessageXML).Element("IDThatIWant")
```

However, to separate SQL and XML and including the restriction (only if element has attribute) it would be something like:

```
var messageXml = from messages in dbContext.Messages
                           join transactions in dbContext.Transactions
                           on messages.TransactionID equals transactions.TransactionID 
                           where transactions.CreatedOn >= StartDate
                           && transactions.CreatedOn <= EndDate
                           select messages.MessageXML;

var messages = from m in messageXml select XElement.Parse(m);

var ids = (from msg in messages
            let id = msg.Attribute("IDThatIWant")
            where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) 
            select Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToList<int>();
```